# Simple Android Broadcast does not show toast

Tags: android

I'm just trying to create a simple broadcast in Androids activity but its not working.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED"); 

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED");

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


        }
    }
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="usb.usbd"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />    

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".UsbddActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
                        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

The screen shows on my Xoom but the toast does not display. The Xoom is connected through the USB so it should display the toast/

Comment: The receiver registration looks okay, the intent looks okay... but where is the code for actually sending the broadcast?

Comment: "Not working" is definitely not enough information to go from. Hey, my car is "not working", can you determine a solution from that? Also - your Intent i = new Intent("...");, why do you have quotes?android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED I think is a final constant in that class. This may not matter though.

Comment: Jack, When I take the quotes off from the intent i = new intent(".."), Eclipse marks it wrong 'cannot be resolved to a variable'

Comment: Maximus. Thats a good question. I dont have one, and thats probably why it is not working.  Thanks.

Comment: @Maximus OS should send those broadcasts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't launch a dialog (and shouldn't launch a toast) from **within** a `BroadcastReceiver`. Instead have the `BroadcastReceiver` launch another component (Activity/Service, etc) that does something. TO show a `Toast` just make another `Activity` and invoke it, or make a method on your current `Activity` that shows it and call that. The entire idea of a receiver is that you do as little as possible inside `onReceive` and get out, it's wiring, it's not where you do work.

[BroadcastReceiver JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)

*This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent broadcast. During this time you can use the other methods on BroadcastReceiver to view/modify the current result values. The function is normally called within the main thread of its process, so you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed). You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation of onReceive().*

**You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation of onReceive()**

Comment: Why it is checked as an answer, when it doesn't answer why your receiver doesn't work? Toast can be called from within receiver, it takes less then a second. Just to check that broadcast receiver works toast is okay.

Comment: @Maxim "You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation of onReceive()" is present in the *answer*, twice. I haven't tried this explicitly, so maybe what you're saying is Toast will work even if Dialog is not allowed? Either way though it's pointless and it's not what the receiver is intended for, the answer is don't do that (and the answer provides the correct way to accomplish the overall goal).

Comment: I mentioned only about Toast, I tried Toast explicitly, that's why I'm saying it works. The question was "Why receiver does not show toast?" author is not trying to launch a dialog, which I agree won`t work here. If toast works, as I mentioned, it means his receiver should work and toast should be shown but it doesn`t. The only reason why it doesn`t because OS doesn`t send broadcasts for UMS_CONNECTED and UMS_DISCONNECTED, they are already deprecated. That`s why toast is not shown. Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Oh god! A book told me to call a Toast inside Receiver(maybe just want to do something looks like console log), I'm pretty sure callback function has called, but no toast shown, I got stucked so I searched for stackoverflow ... What kind of book is that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this toast function:

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

I also faced similar kind of problem in my app, then i changed getApplicationContext() to getBaseContext(), then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such events broadcasted by Android OS, therefore your receiver doesn't receive anything and doesn't show toast. I spent bunch of time trying to catch something when device plugged or unplugged to/from usb, but seems nothing is broadcasted for these actions.