# Broadcast Receiver dont receive intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have one of my services broadcast an intent.

```
public static final String WHATSAPP_INTENT = "com.timelinestudios.ourapp.WHATSAPPSHARER";
Intent sharerintent
```

...

```
 System.out.println("Sending intent");
sharerintent = new Intent(WHATSAPP_INTENT);
sharerintent.putExtra("TRACK_PATH", track.getPath());
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(sharerintent);
System.out.println("Intent Sent");
```

Then I put in a receiver.,

```
public class WhatsappSharer extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String WHATSAPP_INTENT = "com.timelinestudios.ourapp.WHATSAPPSHARER";
public WhatsappSharer() {
}

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    System.out.println("Intent Received");
    if(intent.getAction().equals(WHATSAPP_INTENT)){
        System.out.println("Intent Received");
        Toast ts = Toast.makeText(context, "Ready to share to whatsapp",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ts.show();
    }
}
```

}

Also in Manifest, I added,

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.timelinestudios.ourapp.WhatsappSharer"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.timelinestudios.ourapp.WHATSAPPSHARER"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In Logcat, I am getting 2 System printlns from my service.,
Sending Intent
Intent Sent

But got no system print or toast from the receiver. So i guess, the broadcast receiver is not getting it. What may be the problem?

EDIT: It works when dynamically declaring a broadcast receiver in mainactivity. Wierd. Why is that so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770620/simple-android-broadcast-does-not-show-toast check whether this helps

Comment: this is the advice if it's not worked then ignore it plz,remove this line in your intent filters <action android:name="com.timelinestudios.ourapp.WHATSAPPSHARER"></action>

Comment: @farhan that line is specifying when to trigger this receiver

Comment: @all.. Thank you.. But no helpful comments. Any other?

Answer (score 0):

Change name of your receiver in manifest. Your receiver class name is not same as what you gave in manifest.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".WhatsappSharer"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.timelinestudios.ourapp.WHATSAPPSHARER"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: No. Thats not it. com.timelinestudios.ourapp is my package name. So ecllipse auto added that to the name. Your suggession also implies the same. Anyway, to confirm, I tried your suggession. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Do you send the broadcast from another app than in which your receiver is located?

If so, **remove android:exported="false" (or set it to true).**

When you add an intent filter to the registration of a receiver, it gets exported by default, unless you set it explicitly to false.

Comment: Same app.. Different packages.. I tried putting the broadcast receiver in the same package as that of the broadcasting service, but no hope. BTW it works with dynamic creation of receiver in the mainactivity. Why would that be so?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your AndroidManifest.xml:
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

Also, if doing just that doesn't work, try setting the exported to true